# what scenario should abstract class used in java?

Tags: java, class, oop, interface, abstract-class

I am not familiar in OOPS concept, I have doubt while using abstract class, please clear my doubt.

I have four classes ex: class A, class B, class C and Main class.

class A, B and C contains same method name but the method definition is different

the implementation is like,

```
    class A                          
    {
       getValue();
       setValue();
    }

    class B                          
    {
       getValue();
       setValue();
}

    class C                          
    {
       getValue();
       setValue();
    }
```

In the Main class, I need to call setValue() or getValue(), it can be any of the above three class, how to implement this scenario?

```
    class Main
    {
      Main()
    {}
        x.setValue();
        x.getValue();
    }
```

where x can be Object for either class A or class B or class C.

Answer (score 3):

The abstract class defines, what methods are available. In your case, this would be

```
abstract class YourAbstractClass {
     abstract public int getValue();
     abstract public void setValue(int i);
}
```

Now your classes A, B and C can inherit this class.

```
class A extends YourAbstractClass {
     public int getValue() { return 23; }
     public void setValue(int i) { /* set i */ }
}
class B extends YourAbstractClass {
     public int getValue() { return -3; }
     public void setValue(int i) { /* set i */ }
}
class C extends YourAbstractClass {
     public int getValue() { return 3; }
     public void setValue(int i) { /* set i */ }
}
```

In your main class you can use it the like this:

```
public class Execution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YourAbstractClass o = new A();
        o.getValue();
        o.setValue(3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case you don't need an abstract class but an interface:

```
public interface I {
   Object getValue();
   Object setValue();
}
```

Then your 3 classes A, B and C must implement this interface:

```
class A implements I {
   Object getValue() {...}
   void setValue( someParam) {...}
}

    class B implements I {
   Object getValue() {...}
   void setValue( someParam) {...}
}

class C implements I {
   Object getValue() {...}
   void setValue( someParam) {...}
}
```

And finally in your main class:

```
class Main
{
  Main()
{
    I x = callWhateverYouWantReturningABOrC();
    x.setValue();
    x.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement that in a couple of ways:

```
public interface Valuable {
    void getValue();
    void setValue();
}

class A  implements Valuable {
   getValue() { ... }
   setValue() { ... }
}

class B  implements Valuable {
   getValue() { ... }
   setValue() { ... }
}

class C  implements Valuable {
   getValue() { ... }
   setValue() { ... }
}
```

Or ...

```
abstract class Valuable {
    void getValue() { ... }
    void setValue() { ... }
}

class A extends Valuable {
}

class B extends Valuable {
}

class C extends Valuable {
}
```

Or ... a hybrid where you both interfaces and abstract classes.

Which is more appropriate depends on a number of things, including whether the method implementations are the same or not.  If they are, then the `abstract` class eliminates some duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you want to create an interface:

```
interface I {
  int getValue();
  void setValue(int x);
}
```

and your classes will implement it:

```
class A implements I {..};
class B implements I {..};
class C implements I {..};
```

Then in your Main class you can have method, which doesn't have to know which concrete implementation of I the `x` variable is (wheather `A`, `B` or `C`) and it can call it's methods:

```
{
  I x = new A(); // or new B() or C()
  x.setValue(1);
  x.getValue();
}
```

Comment: I can able to do this operation by using abstract class itself right, then why should I go for Interface?

Comment: In Java, you can inherit just from one class, but multiple interfaces. So generally you should use interfaces for classes, where you don't need default method implementation (although in Java 8, it is also possible in interfaces). So when you just want to define common call signature, use interface. E.g. interface `Persistable` with methods `load()` and `save()`. Where you have some implementation and you just to specify some detail (i.e. implement abstract method), use abstract class. E.g. AbstractListModel in swing library.

Comment: class Main
{
  Main()
{
    I x = callWhateverYouWantReturningABOrC();
    x.setValue();
    x.getValue();
}                                           I have an api Z() which returns any of these three class eg: x Z(); in this scenario how will I cast x to corresponding Class (A or B or C) ?, I need like ((A/B/C)x) Z();

Comment: The point is that you never cast to concrete class (`A` or `B` or `C`), you just use type `I` and don't care which class it is. The interface `I` contains common features (methods) of its descendants and you have to use just them. So make `z()` return `I`: `public I z() { }`

Answer (score 0):

You can make Main an interface.
interface is a pure abstract class.

```
public interface Main {
   void setValue();
   void getValue();
}
```

Then make A, B, and C classes to implement the Main interface

```
public class A implements Main {
   @Override
   public void setValue() {
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public void getValue() {
      ...
   }
}

public class B implements Main {
   @Override
   public void setValue() {
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public void getValue() {
      ...
   }
}


public class C implements Main {
   @Override
   public void setValue() {
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public void getValue() {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all, I got the solution from you guys .. one more doubt at what scenario I should use Interface, if I am not wrong, this case is right,           a case where all the methods should be implemented?